# convert video file into flv formate using jsp

Tags: java

in my webpage i want to convert uploaded video file into flv formate using jsp or servlets

Comment: Then do so. *We* won’t stop you.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://fmj-sf.net/ for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Either call out to [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) to do the conversion as a batch file, or use a library such as [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) to do the conversion in Java.